# What memory are the USB device descriptors stored in?

Tags: memory, usb, descriptor

Good day.

After studying the literature, I could not find information about the storage location of the USB device `descriptors(bDescriptorType etc)`.

In which section of the memory are they stored?

And how can they be changed so that the device is identified incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

The memory used for descriptors is an internal implementation detail of each USB device, so you will not find any information about it in the USB specification.  If you have a microcontroller with flash memory, that is usually the most logical place to store the descriptors, since the desctiptors generally do not change at runtime and flash memory is generally the most plentiful on a microcontroller.  You could successfully store them in EEPROM or RAM if you wanted to.

If you are developing a USB device using a microcontroller, you generally specify the descriptors somewhere in the source code of the firmware.  After you compile the firmware and load it onto the device using a programmer, you usually will have no need to change the descriptors.